# Dozer: Is it possible to one-way exclude a field on all mapped classes?

Tags: java, jpa, dozer

I want to exclude all 'createdDate' fields from being deserialized on all of my mapped fields:

**Similar to this:**

`<field-exclude type="one-way""> 
  <a>createdDate</a> 
  <b>createdDate</b> 
</field-exclude>`

Thus, having the field visible when querying but not updatable.

Is there a way to do this globally without having to specify it on each and every mapping?

Answer (score 0):

Move all your common fields to super class on source and destination classes. and create mapping for super classes. Full example can be found at [Dozer fields - Global Exclude Example](http://www.codesimplify.com/java/dozer/dozer-global-exclude-fields-example/)

**Step 1:Source POJOs:**

```
    //PersonType.java
public class AddressType extends BaseType{

    private String addrLine1;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private int zipCode;
    // Setter and Getter methods are removed
}
// BaseType.java
public class BaseType { 
        private String createdDate;
    // Setter and Getter methods are removed
}
```

**Step 2: Target POJOs:**

```
// Address.java
public class Address extends BaseDomain{

    private String addrLine1;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private int zip5;
// Setter and Getter methods are removed
}
//BaseDomain.java
public class BaseDomain {   
    private String createdDate;
// Setter and Getter methods are removed
}
```

**Step 3: Create Mapping**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mappings xmlns="http://dozer.sourceforge.net"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://dozer.sourceforge.net
          http://dozer.sourceforge.net/schema/beanmapping.xsd">
     <mapping>
            <class-a>com.codesimplify.dozersamples.fieldexclude.AddressType</class-a>
            <class-b>com.codesimplify.dozersamples.fieldexclude.Address</class-b>   
    </mapping>

   <mapping>
    <class-a>com.codesimplify.dozersamples.fieldexclude.BaseType</class-a>
    <class-b>com.codesimplify.dozersamples.fieldexclude.BaseDomain</class-b>
    <field-exclude type="one-way">
        <a>createdDate</a>
        <b>createdDate</b>
    </field-exclude>    
    </mapping>
</mappings>
```